# VBA excel-2010 listbox1.SelectedIndex throws error

Tags: vba, excel-2010

Hi I am inside an excel workbook and in the same worksheet I wrote VBA to delete the currently selected item from a list box but the function SelectedIndex said it is not a method of the listbox. I am not sure why this is happening since I see many examples use this. Any help would be awesome!

Code:

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt (ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
ListBox1.RemoveItem ListBox1.ListIndex
```

you may want to add a check about any item being actually selected:

```
With Me.ListBox1
    If .ListIndex <> -1 Then .RemoveItem .ListIndex
End With
```